Second Argument of \fontsize{}{}\selectfont Not Working in a Pspicture
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,top=0in,paperwidth=5.0in,paperheight=8in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}

\newcommand{\onequote}[2]{%
  \par\noindent\textit{#1}{\vspace*{-8pt}}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash#2%
 % \par\noindent\textbf{#1}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\textit{#2}%
}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\definecolor{armygreen}{rgb}{0.29, 0.33, 0.13}
\setmainfont{Cabin}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{pspicture}(-6.35,0)(6.35,20.32)%

\psframe[fillcolor=armygreen,fillstyle=solid](-6.35,0)(6.35,20.32)%
\psframe[linecolor=armygreen](-6.35,0)(6.35,20.32)% draws frame.

\rput[tc](0.45,12.25){\begin{minipage}{3.75in}\lipsum[3]\end{minipage}}


\rput[tc](1.00,6.75){\begin{minipage}{3.75in}{\textcolor{yellow}{ %\scriptsize 
\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{\onequote{Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book. It usually begins with: ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.''}{Author}}}}\end{minipage}}


\rput[tc](1.00,2.75){\begin{minipage}{3.75in}{\textcolor{yellow}{\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book. It usually begins with: ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.''}}}\end{minipage}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

which produces:

QUESTION: Why does the command \fontsize{8pt}{}\selectfont not work within a pspicture environment? If you fill in different values for the second argument in the MWE, nothing different happens---it seems to assume the vertical spacing present in the first (lorem ipsum) paragraph. How may I adjust the vertical spacing between the lines of a scaled quote (2nd paragraph) or a scaled paragraph (the third in the display) when within a pspicture environment?
Remark: I am enclosing the text within a minipage in order to get it to display in paragraph form within the pspicture.
Thank you.

I believed that problem was not because of pspicture, actually it was due to the command \textcolor also unnecessary groupings, and the modified MWE is:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,top=0in,paperwidth=5.0in,paperheight=8in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}

\newcommand{\onequote}[2]{%
  \par\noindent\textit{#1}{\vspace*{-8pt}}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash#2%
 % \par\noindent\textbf{#1}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\textit{#2}%
}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\definecolor{armygreen}{rgb}{0.29, 0.33, 0.13}
\setmainfont{Cabin}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{pspicture}(-6.35,0)(6.35,20.32)%

\psframe[fillcolor=armygreen,fillstyle=solid](-6.35,0)(6.35,20.32)%
\psframe[linecolor=armygreen](-6.35,0)(6.35,20.32)% draws frame.

\rput[tc](0.45,12.25){\begin{minipage}{3.75in}\lipsum[3]\end{minipage}}


\rput[tc](1.00,6.75){\begin{minipage}{3.75in} %\scriptsize 
\fontsize{8pt}{22pt}\selectfont\color{yellow}{\onequote{Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book. It usually begins with: ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.''}{Author}}\par\end{minipage}}


\rput[tc](1.00,2.75){\begin{minipage}{3.75in}\fontsize{8pt}{22pt}\selectfont\color{yellow}Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book. It usually begins with: ``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.''\end{minipage}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

For checking purpose, I've changed the leading as 22pt, you can change what you likes.


Thank you for your very fine answer. As you suggested, I changed the 22pt to 4pt which is more in line with the 8pt font size. Perhaps you might want to post a more aesthetically pleasing picture to go along with your very helpful answer.

Thanks for your kind words

@DDS don't use 4pt as the second argument if the first is 8pt! 8pt high letter will not fit on lines that are 4pt apart.

@DavidCarlisle Yes; actually, in the actual document I discovered that 4pt would not be good. I am using 12pt to go along with the 8pt. (I don't know why 4pt didn't look so bad in practice.)

@DDS you won't get 4pt spacinmg you will get \lineskip so the lines will not be evenly spaced but made as large as the content, so if your text is regular it may look ok but a line with an accented capital will have different space than a line with all lowercase

@DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. I hope \fontsize{8pt}{12pt}\selectfont is OK. It seems to me to be (but I've been wrong before.)

the group after \color{yellow}... in the first paragraph isn't doing anything (but I'm not sure if that is the point of that line?)
